# Ding liren is 2nd in the asia, who first?

Tags: fide

It's says that he's second, but isn't he first?

https://ratings.fide.com/profile/8603677

Comment: This is a question for FIDE not Chess SE. In a year's time it will be useless and I don't think it is particularly useful now.

Comment: @BrianTowers By that time, Hu may indeed be on first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FIDE says he's 1st for active Asian players, so there can only be one inactive player who still has a rating so high: [Garry Kasparov!](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/4100018) (apparently somehow rank 0 among active players)